# How to plug in additional TimeZoneNamesBundle?

Tags: java, resources, timezone

I'm using Java 1.8.60 and I need to add Russian timezone names. How can I do it? Is there additional bundles?

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.8  (aka Java 8) already comes with the full list of tzdb time zones installed, including Russian time zones.  You can find the full list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

You can check to see which versions of the tzdb are shipped with each JRE release [in this table](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html).  It looks like 1.8.60 (aka 8u60) shipped with tzdata 2015e.  There have been two updates to the tzdb since then (at the time of writing this post).  Neither affect Russian time zones, but you can use the [tzupdater tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) if you want to use a more current version without updating the JRE.

If you were looking for something more specific, please edit your question.